# How To Add To A ThemeData Variable After Declaration?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a unique circumstance where it would save myself a lot of time if I could add a property to a ThemeData variable after declaration.

Currently my ThemeData is declared inside a themes.dart file:

```
ThemeData lightTheme() {
  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: "Open Sans",
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme(),
    textTheme: textTheme(),
    inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationTheme(),
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  );
}

TextTheme textTheme() {
  return TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xFF000000),
          //fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(25) I would like to declare this in a different file
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
  )
}
```

The ThemeData is later used in main.dart in the typical theme: lightTheme() as a MaterialApp property

I then want to change the fontSize of the headline1 TextTheme inside my body.dart file where I use the headline1 textTheme:

```
Text(
  'Hello,',
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1, //I want to add a line for fontSize here 
),
```

How can I do that? Help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.copyWith()` as:

`style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.copyWith(fontSize: 17)`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much :)

Comment: Happy to help you. :)